# MVC 5 Trying to register new account and getting "Invalid column name 'UserName'."

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Here is my AccountController.cs

```
namespace Leepio.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/VerifyCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
            if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/VerifyCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(VerifyCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // The following code protects for brute force attacks against the two factor codes. 
            // If a user enters incorrect codes for a specified amount of time then the user account 
            // will be locked out for a specified amount of time. 
            // You can configure the account lockout settings in IdentityConfig
            var result = await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(model.Provider, model.Code, isPersistent:  model.RememberMe, rememberBrowser: model.RememberBrowser);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(model.ReturnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid code.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }


        // GET: /Account/Register
         [AllowAnonymous]
         public ActionResult Register()
         {
             return View();
         }

         //
         // POST: /Account/Register
         [HttpPost]
         [AllowAnonymous]
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
         public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterStudentViewModel model)
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 var user = new ApplicationUser
                 {
                     UserName = model.FirstName,
                     Email = model.Email,
                     Role = "studentRole"
                 };
                 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                 UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, user.Role); 
                 if (result.Succeeded)
                 {

                     await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                     // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                     // Send an email with this link
                     // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                     // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                     // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");



                     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                 }
                 AddErrors(result);
             }

             // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
             return View(model);
         }






        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult RegisterStudent()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterStudent(RegisterStudentViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                   Email = model.Email,
                   FirstName = model.FirstName,
                   LastName = model.LastName,
                   City = model.City,
                   ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
                   Region = model.Region,
                   Language = model.Language,
                   University = model.University,
                   StudyProgramme = model.StudyProgramme,
                   Semester = model.Semester,
                   GraduationDate = model.GraduationDate,
                   Description = model.Description,
                   Skills = model.Skills,
                   Experience = model.Experience,
                   Role = "studentRole"
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, user.Role); 
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");



                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }


        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompany()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterCompany(RegisterCompanyViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {

                    //CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Role = "companyRole",
                    City = model.City,
                    ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
                    Region = model.Region,
                 //   NrEmployees = model.NrEmployees,
                  //  WorkField = model.WorkField,
                    Language = model.Language,
                    Description = model.Description
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, user.Role); 
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");



                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }





        //
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
        {
            return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/SendCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var userFactors = await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(userId);
            var factorOptions = userFactors.Select(purpose => new SelectListItem { Text = purpose, Value = purpose }).ToList();
            return View(new SendCodeViewModel { Providers = factorOptions, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/SendCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(SendCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Generate the token and send it
            if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(model.SelectedProvider))
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = model.SelectedProvider, ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "canEdit");
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_userManager != null)
                {
                    _userManager.Dispose();
                    _userManager = null;
                }

                if (_signInManager != null)
                {
                    _signInManager.Dispose();
                    _signInManager = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Here is some code from AccountViewModels.cs

```
    public class RegisterStudentViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Region")]
        public string Region { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "University")]
        public string University { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Study programme")]
        public string StudyProgramme { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Semester")]
        public int Semester { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Graduation Date")]
        public string GraduationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Skills")]
        public string Skills { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Experience")]
        public string Experience { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


    public class RegisterCompanyViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zip code")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Region")]
        public string Region { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Number of employees")]
        public string NrEmployees { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Field of work")]
        public string WorkField { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my IdentityModels.cs

```
namespace Leepio.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        public string City { get; set; }
     //   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
      //  public string NrEmployees { get; set; }
      //  public string WorkField { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string University { get; set; }
        public int Semester { get; set; }
        public string GraduationDate { get; set; }
        public string Skills { get; set; }
        public string Experience { get; set; }
        public string StudyProgramme { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {

        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this strange error when trying to register for a student account: Invalid column name 'UserName'.
But I no longer have UserName in my database. I removed it and then updated it. What could be the cause?
The account should be registered at the "var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);" line in RegisterStudent.

Comment: Why would you remove `UserName`?  Seems like a pretty vital field for identity management.

Comment: Also, for future reference please make an attempt to narrow down the code you post to only the relevant pieces.  Like what line is generating the error and and relevant, dependent functions.

Comment: Well because i do not want users having usernames. There would be no point to them. Sorry foo putting up lots of code, I was not sure about it myself so I decided to enter most of the classes.

Comment: How do you identify a user if not by username, though?  Are you using email address as a key?

Comment: the primary key is an unique generated ID, from what I saw, won't that be enough? Should I stick with usernames also?

Comment: I'll ask it this way - when users log into your system, what do they use as their identity?

Comment: Email and password

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove UserName - it is required by the class IdentityUser which implements IUser.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613291(v=vs.108).aspx